# Изменение метаданных музыки

Tags: python

У меня есть сырой mp3 файл без тегов. Я хочу прочитать/изменить артиста и альбомную фотографию.

Я попробовал использовать stagger

```
import stagger
tags = stagger.read_tag("test.mp3")
```

Получил ошибку:

```
  File "C:\Users\Kuchizu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\stagger\tags.py", line 81, in read_tag
(cls, offset, length) = detect_tag(file)
File "C:\Users\Kuchizu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\stagger\tags.py", line 108, in detect_tag
    raise NoTagError("ID3v2 tag not found")
stagger.errors.NoTagError: ID3v2 tag not found
```

Попробовал использовать eyed3

```
import eyed3
music = eyed3.load("test.mp3")
music.tag.artist = 'artist'
music.tag.save()
print(music.tag.ratist)
```

Получил ошибку:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tag'
```

Также попробовал сделать так:

```
import stagger
tag = stagger.Tag24()
tag.artist = "Artist"
tag.picture = 'photo.jpg'
tag.write("test.mp3")
```

Но тогда музыку не получается воспроизвести сколько бы я не пробовал.

Я в отчаянии, помогите.

Comment: test.mp3 надо посмотреть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать библиотеку [eyed3](https://eyed3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
import eyed3

audio_file = eyed3.load("song.mp3")
audio_file.tag.artist = "Token Entry"
audio_file.tag.album = "Free For All Comp LP"
audio_file.tag.album_artist = "Various Artists"
audio_file.tag.title = "The Edge"
audio_file.tag.track_num = 3

audio_file.tag.save()
```

Со своей задачей справляется.

Comment: В моем случае оно возвращает None объект т.к это сырой mp3 файл без тегов

Comment: Так Вы запишите туда, что-нибудь. Естественно оно будет None если там нет ничего.
audio_file.tag.artist = "Token Entry"
audio_file.tag.save()

Comment: У Вас получилось?

Comment: Нет не получилось.

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tag'

Comment: Приложите Ваш код.  Как так у Вас получилось вчера, а сегодня уже нет. И приложите ссылку на этот загадочный файл мп3

Comment: У меня работает с обычной музой но не работает с простым mp3 файлом без тегов. Использовал код который вы написали.

Comment: Вот ссылка на файл: https://dropmefiles.com/6sGZw

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120136/discussion-between-kuchizu-and-sergey-glukhov).